# Message driven bean and database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jms

I followed the following tutorial of Netbeans on creating the Enterprise Application using the IDE. I just wanted to know why the usage of Message driven bean is preferred here for the save or persist method? And why not for the other database operations such as findAll?

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html

Answer (score 0):

Message Driven Beans are asynchronous components, to illustrate the concept, asynchronous communication works pretty much like email communication, you send the email and that's it, you can only hope for the best, and expect that the recipient processes your mail as soon as possible and reply back if necessary (in a different communication), on the other hand, synchronous communication works pretty much like a phone call, you get your response during the same communication, without the need to start a new one.

In your case, when a client invokes `findAll` he's quite likely expecting to get a list of results in the same communication (synchronously: 'server, give me right now all the customers in the system'), in which case an MDB (asynchronous) is simply useless, on the other hand, when a client invokes `save` he might not want to wait for an answer (asynchronously: 'server, just try to save this info, i don't need to know right now if you succeeded or not').

There's a lot more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html).